# Launch Arguments in Xcode schemes

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I'm looking at SwiftMonkey. The link is:
https://github.com/zalando/SwiftMonkey

They say to use command line flags as in:

```
   if CommandLine.arguments.contains("--MonkeyPaws") {
        paws = MonkeyPaws(view: window!)
    }
```

and say to use command line flags:

```
let application = XCUIApplication()

application.launchArguments = ["--MonkeyPaws"]
```

I tried to do this in Xcode by creating a new scheme for UITesting and then add the arguments on launch:

[image]
This works for the main scheme, but not for the UITests (the arguments don't exist when I place the arguments on either the Run or the Test sections of the Schemes).

I can launch the tests from the simulator:

```
xcodebuild -workspace SwiftMonkeyTutorial.xcworkspace -scheme "SwiftMonkeyTutorialUITests" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=12.2' test
```

but adding an argument as following yields an error of "invalid option '-- MonkeyPaws'"

```
xcodebuild -workspace SwiftMonkeyTutorial.xcworkspace -scheme "SwiftMonkeyTutorialUITests" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=12.2' test --MonkeyPaws
```

How can I pass arguments to my scheme?

Comment: Did you mistype `MoneyPaws` as `MonkeyPass` in the last code block?

Comment: Well, yes but it's irrelevant as still is not an accepted argument

Comment: What are you trying to ultimately achieve with this? i.e. why can't you use the launchArguments var on XCUIApplication?

Comment: @Oletha That is the answer (I didn't know about launch arguments). If you want credit, write as an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send launch arguments from UI tests to the application under test using the `launchArguments` property on `XCUIApplication`:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments = ["--MonkeyPaws"]
app.launch()
```